# Calling a member function of a class?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have created a subclass of NSImageView- let's call it MyView- and have added a member function to it - let's call it "The Function". I additionally created three model classes.

Then using Interface Builder, I placed three cells of MyView into my window, therefore at runtime there would be three object instances of it. **What I need to do is have my model classes call "The Function" from the three MyView instances/cells at runtime. How would I do this?**

For example:

Model Classes: Class A, Class B, Class C

At runtime I want:

- Class A to call The Function from the first first cell/instance of MyView
- Class B to call The Function from the first second cell/instance of MyView
- Class C to call The Function from the first third cell/instance of MyView

Note the following:

- TheFunction is a member function of MyView
- I am creating an app for Mac OSX not iOS
- I am using Xcode 3.2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are completely violating the concept of MVC (Model View Controller). By theoretically we should never call any method from a model to view or vice versa.

You can create an outlet inside controller of your view and then a controller should be the one that delivers the data of view to the Model.

So I assume you have ViewControllers? If yes then create your image view outlets inside your ViewController and then let your controller have the instance of the Model inside your ViewController, you then have instance of Model and View inside Controller and in that you can interchange data between those instance